# How to find the shortest path between two points on the chessboard?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Given the rules of movement of a certain piece, say a horse (or knight) or whatever else it is called, how would one calculate the shortest path between where the piece presently is and another given point on the chessboard?

I am not looking for code, but just thoughts. I am looking for the algorithm.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may consider asking this on cs.stackexchange.com or providing additional details. Are we to handle only the existing pieces or can one define a new piece with arbitrary moves? How do we handle if we can not reach a certain location? (e.g. having a bishop on black trying to reach a white destination) What are the bounds on the size of the grid?

Comment: Thank you. Good points. I have the answers in my head but I will edit the question to fill in these details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) as the path finding algorithm where in each step your next stop will be the all probable moves by the piece.

Comment: But DFS doesn't find the shortest path. I think he only need BFS

Comment: A bit modification in DFS would solve the problem, but i think it'd create some more confusion. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: A* ("DFS with heuristics") would return single shortest path. But I used two start points BFS when generating all possible shortest paths for knight (cs course assigment). BFS was fast enough because I run out of memory to list all possible routes in UI before runtime became noticeable (around 20 squares distance generate close to 1M shortest routes).